# How to make my search fuzzy

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I can get a particular list on to the top using a single value. How can I make my search fuzzy so that it accepts any data of `odata` on list?

```
var sf = new sap.m.SearchField({
                        placeholder: "Search",
                        showRefreshButton: true,
                    liveChange: function(oEvent) {
var tpmla = oEvent.getParameter("newValue");
var filters = new Array();
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Kunnr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, tpmla);
                         filters.push(oFilter);
                         this.oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("po_list");
                         this.oList.getBinding("items").filter(filters);})
```

I need to understand how can I give more inputs of type `Name1, Addr.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple filters to a `sap.ui.model.ListBinding`:

```
var filters = [];
filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Kunnr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, tpmla));
filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, tpmla));
filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Addr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, tpmla));

this.oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("po_list");
this.oList.getBinding("items").filter(filters);
```

As far as I remember this will link the different filters with an AND relationship meaning it only matches if `tmpla` is contained in ALL of the fields. There is no way to make this an OR. The workaround is to just create a search field on your model which contains all values that you might search for as a concatenated string.

BR
Chris

Comment: Hi cschuff, actually you can define OR relationships for filters, please see my answer below.

Comment: Nice, thx for the hint. Can't find this in the docs though :/ you never stop learning :)

Answer (score 1):

For `AND` relationship, please check the answer of @cschuff.

Actually you can define `OR` relationship of the search fields using `new sap.ui.model.Filter(aFilters, bAnd);`If bAnd is set all filters within the filter will be ANDed else they will be ORed.

```
var filters = [];
filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Kunnr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, tpmla));
filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, tpmla));
filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Addr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, tpmla));
var orFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter(filters,false);

this.oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("po_list");
this.oList.getBinding("items").filter([orFilters]);
```